# How can i move to any other activity with jfeinstein slider library

Tags: android, onclick, slidingmenu, buttonclick

I have implemented [**jfeinstein10**](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) slider menu library in my application. With this piece of code I am successfully able to implement slider in my app.

Now my question is how can I move to next activity using this slider? The following image shows how my slider looks like:

[image]

So basically I want to move to next activity or any other activity when I click on any of the options from slider. Like for example, when I click on Comment or Post or Chat or any other option I want to go to the relevant screen. Hope this is clear. Still if you need more explanation you can ask.

Following is my code snippet.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.5f);
        menu.attachToActivity(MainActivity.this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_menu);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slidingMenu);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                menu.showMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The activity with the slide menu extends SlideMenuActivity right?

Comment: @amalBit, No it extends `Activity` only.

Comment: @amalBit, you can check example here it self, https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu., If you scroll down you will find example under `Simple Example`.

Comment: Try this: menu.findViewbyid(R.id.yourMenuOption).setOnClickListenr(this)

Comment: I have defined menu `final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);` Like this, so there is no ID of menu.

Comment: @amalBit, and i have already tried with, `menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override public void onClick(View arg0) {switch (arg0.getId()) { case R.id.comment:`.... but it doesn't work either.

Comment: How about menu.getMenu().findviewbyid(YourViewId).setOnclickListner(listner);

Comment: @amalBit, But how can i use findviewbyid for menu as there is no ID for menu.

Comment: Is your slidemenu working?.. if so you must have a layout defined for the slidemenu, then they must have ID for each view of the sideMenu.

Comment: @amalBit, Thank you it's working now. If you want you can post this as a answer.

Comment: I added it as the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the onclick listenrs to the Menu layout that you have appended to the Main Activity like so:

```
  menu.getMenu().findViewById(R.id.yourSideMenuOption).setOnClickLister(this);
```

Its advisable to use an abstract activity, so that you are not using the same code over and over in each of your activity.

Comment: how can i do abstract activity so that i can avoid my hard work by not writing same code multiple time.?

Comment: Well, instead of extending your activity class directly to Activity. You can extend to a Custom class that you defined(which extends the activity).  Now you can add the common code for all the activity there. and extend this Custom activity class from all your other activities